# Using One Field Of table Derived SampleID and Number

Tags: sql

I have table ROWDATA and its Column SampleID comming 3 times With [image]

Now I want to SampleID Like S10335-04 AND Number Like 10 AND Only One Time

Comment: you should split Sample ID into three columns, so you can store the "S10335" and the "04X10" and the "1" independently.  You can still make them a composite primary key.  you could then properly store the sequence part as a number and easily increment it with out string manipulation.  You can use a view or computed column to format these three columns with "-" dashes and/or leading zeros for users to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
SELECT DISTINCT substring( substring(sampleid,1,charindex(' - ',sampleiD)) ,1,charindex('X',sampleid)-1) AS SampleID,
substring(sampleid,charindex('X',sampleid)+1,3) AS Number
FROM ROWDATA WHERE SampleID LIKE '%X%'
```